# Theme Studio - Third-party icons

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm creating a large scope theme in Huawei Theme Studio and I'm unable to add third-party icons that I would like to customize.

In the Theme Studio, I am in Icon -> Third-Party Icon and Custom.

In the icon folder which is located in ThemeStudio -> workspace -> mytheme -> icons I tried to add for example: **com.instagram.android.png**, **com.amazon.aa.png**, **com.android.chrome.png**, etc.

Unfortunately, none of them showed up in Theme Studio. I'm attaching a screenshot of the message I got when I was trying to upload them.

[image: message]

Next, I tried to upload icons from Huawei, which the large scope theme does not include. These were **com.huawei.gameassistant.png** and **com.huawei.vdrive.png**, and these two appeared in the third-party icons.

Am I doing something wrong, or Huawei doesn't support most third-party icons?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/content/themes-specification-upgrade-0000001160790879#section131676155164), If a theme is designed for phones running EMUI 10.0 or later, its preview images cannot contain the 21 icons below, or content related to GMS such as Google Search. Therefore, you do not need to create these images.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to ask one more question about this topic - is there any other way, how to change these well known third-party icons? I'm asking because I was looking at icon sets in Huawei theme store that contain many third party icons.

Comment: yes@nub, maybe you could refer to this [specification](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/content/themes-specification-0000001160896163#section782985321712).